# Quotient module of a sum of R-modules

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ an ideal of $R$, $M$ a finitely-generated $R$-module, and $N$ a submodule of $M$ such that $M = N + IM$.

The text I am reading asserts that it is trivial to show: $(N+IM)/N \cong (IM)/(IM \cap N)$. Trivial or not, I'm struggling to do it. How do we prove this?

Comment: When you want to show $M/N \cong P/Q$ the standard procedure is to find a well defined map from $M \to P/Q$ such that $N$ is kernel of the map. So can you think of a natural map from $N + IM\to IM/(IM\cap N)$?

Comment: Isn't this just a special case of the second isomorphism theorem?

Comment: @Mark so it is! Although this particular text doesn't prove said theorem until later, so for now I guess TonyPizza has the right idea, although in this case I think it's easier to find a map $ IM \to (N+IM)/N $ (just taking $ x \mapsto x + N $ works, right?)

Comment: @Mark Please consider converting that to a solution to remove this question from comment-answered-limbo!